# Trying to drop UNIQUE but fails due to dependencies, but can't find any

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, dependencies

I have a table with a UNIQUE KEY which I need to remove, however I get the following error when I try to:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 
Cannot drop index 'unique_style_within_seasons_customer_etc': 
needed in a foreign key constraint 
(SQL: ALTER TABLE styles DROP INDEX unique_style_within_seasons_customer_etc)
```

There are no dependencies on that UNIQUE KEY, only to one of the columns in the table. I am unsure what to do next? The following returns nothing:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    COLUMN_NAME, 
    CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, 
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'knit' AND
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'styles' AND
    CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%unique_style_within_seasons_customer_etc%';
```

The only reference to that table is style_versions on column styles_id, so none of those listed above. Removing the last line returns:

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | REF_TABLE | REF_COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| style_versions | styles_id | style_versions_styles_id_foreign | styles | id |

---

Show create table output:

```
CREATE TABLE `styles` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `designs_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `departments_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seasons_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customers_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_ref` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `commodity_codes_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `last_updated_by` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `use_version` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `carryover` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` enum('mens','ladies','accessories','childrens') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cancelled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_style_within_seasons_customer_etc` (`designs_id`,`departments_id`,`seasons_id`,`customers_id`,`category`),
  KEY `styles_departments_id_foreign` (`departments_id`),
  KEY `styles_seasons_id_foreign` (`seasons_id`),
  KEY `styles_customers_id_foreign` (`customers_id`),
  KEY `styles_commodity_codes_id_foreign` (`commodity_codes_id`),
  KEY `styles_last_updated_by_foreign` (`last_updated_by`),
  KEY `styles_use_version_foreign` (`use_version`),
  CONSTRAINT `styles_commodity_codes_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`commodity_codes_id`) REFERENCES `commodity_codes` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `styles_customers_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customers_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `styles_departments_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`departments_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `styles_designs_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`designs_id`) REFERENCES `designs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `styles_last_updated_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`last_updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `styles_seasons_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`seasons_id`) REFERENCES `seasons` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `styles_use_version_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`use_version`) REFERENCES `style_versions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=600 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem on some online fiddle. Copy all CREATE TABLE to the fiddle then ensure that DROP INDEX fails. Then provide the link to the fiddle.

Comment: Look for _other_ tables with `FOREIGN KEYs` to this column.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
ALTER TABLE styles
    ADD INDEX UNIQUE KEY (`designs_id`, `departments_id`,
                  `seasons_id`, `customers_id`, `category`);

ALTER TABLE styles
    DROP INDEX `unique_style_within_seasons_customer_etc`;
```